# Making a login session cookie id not theftable by regenerating itself repeatedly

Tags: security, session, cookies, persistent-connection

To counteract login session cookie theft, sniffing etc i've been thinking about this scheme.

i already read http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice and what i wish to do is something less-complicated, maybe performance-wise faster too and something that blends well with both **remember me** functionality and normal session'ed login.

when registration is successful add `session id` to `user(:uid)` table and generate session cookie id for example `d6c89ddba79b4f68be07bd874c5ff566` and store it in user browser.

When user visits another,the same page,refreshes it; another `id` will be generated and the `current id` in the `user(:uid)` table, **the cookie in the user browser** will be updated with the new one making the old one useless || invalid.

If an observer tries to steal the cookie, be it in unprotected connection, for example non-https website it will be rendered useless at user's next visit or refresh.

But... i'm sure there's a flaw somewhere in this logic. can the observer create a sort of time warping technique or do something locally to annihilate the benefits of such a scheme?

One concern comes to mind now.. i think it will be a possible situation that an observer steals the cookie when the user is afk or idle, then the observer refreshes the current page with that cookie or visits another one. the problem is that now the user is logged out while the observer has full grip of his account and can therefore change password if it's not a system where password change is confirmed through email or inserting current password before.

is that right? in that case, how could this scheme be enforced without bringing possibly extra complexity?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a good way to [prevent session sharing](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/56512/8340):

> the server will generate a new Session ID to store in the cookie every n number of requests. The Set-Cookie header will only be sent once, so if there are two browsers logged into the same session, one of them will be using the old, invalid session

---

> is that right? in that case, how could this scheme be enforced without bringing possibly extra complexity?

As you say, you can get the user to confirm their password whenever a high security function is invoked such as password change. You could also get the system to confirm their password to continue the session in the case that session sharing is detected (i.e. some requests have been logged using the old session ID).